# why package-lock.json is not created

Tags: node.js

npm documentation says

> package-lock.json is automatically generated for any operations where npm modifies either the node_modules tree, or package.json.

but after npm install package-lock.json not exists. Why?

Comment: Which version of `node` are you using? Probably an outdated version.

Comment: what version of npm are you using?

Comment: Version is 3.10.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> after npm install package-lock.json not exists.

This is because you are using `npm v3.10.8` and `package-lock.json` was introduced in version `5.0.0`.

> **Feature Summary - Installer changes**
>   * A new, standardised lockfile feature meant for cross-package-manager compatibility (package-lock.json), and a new format and semantics for shrinkwrap. (#16441)

**Source**: [Feature Summary of npm of 5.0.0](https://github.com/npm/npm/releases/tag/v5.0.0)

You need to update the npm to `5.0.0` to get `package-lock.json`. For updating the npm

> npm update [-g] [...]

In your case, it will be

> npm update -g npm

**Source** : [Update a package](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update)

Answer (score 1):

You are running an old version of NPM.

I believe it was npm version 5 where they introduced lock files.

Try upgrading npm to the latest and it will create the lock file you are looking for.

Comment: After `npm install npm@latest -g` version is still `3.10.8`

Comment: Are you on windows or mac?

Comment: If you originally installed npm with node, you should be able to run `sudo npm i -g npm@latest`. If that doesn't work, I would recommend installing npm via brew `brew update && brew install node && npm -g npm`